# Problem with saving session variables in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have an app that requires users to log in in order to use it and I use sessions in PHP in order to accomplish that. The first file `index.ui.php` includes this piece of code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['sent'] == 'sent' ) {
        $msg = fx_login_user( $cn, $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'] );

        if ( $msg == $_POST['email'] ) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['ss_user'] = $_POST['email'];
            
            $job = fx_take_job( $cn, $_POST['email'] );

            if ( $job == 'Tech' ) {
                header("Location: index_tech.php");
                exit;
            } elseif ( $job == 'Admin' ) {
                header("Location: index_admin.php");
                exit;
            } elseif ( $job == 'Root' ) {
                header("Location: index_root.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now, in `ìndex_root.php` (but also all the remaining index pages) I put a `require("session.php")` at the beginning in which I manage the access like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['ss_user'] ) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
?>
```

In that same `index_root.php` I have a form that apart from the data saved in the session variable, gets the value of an entity and tries to save it into `$_SESSION`

Part of **index_root.php**

```
<?php
echo '<form class="form" id="form_info_user_root" method="POST" action="">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="sent_user" value="user">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="session" value="'.$_SESSION['ss_user'].'">';
echo '<input type="submit">';
?>
```

And **form_root.php** (which I include in `index_root.php` with another `require()` just before the one for `session.php`)

```
if ( isset( $_POST ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['sent_user'] == 'user' ) {

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['ss_user'] = $_POST['session'];
        $_SESSION['entity_info'] = substr( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
        strrpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "=" ) + 1 );
        
        header("Location: info_user.php");
    }
}
```

And now, in `info_user.php`, I also have at the beginning `require("session.php")` for the session management, but the two variables saved previously (which I both need for some logic in that page) get lost somehow and therefore, I get kicked out to `index.php`.

I did some logging to know when do I lose the variables (or maybe the session itself), and the ID of the session is the same in every page (as it should be, I guess) so it doesn't get finished, the variables are (as it looks like) properly saved in `form_root.php`, but they disappear once I enter to 'info_user.php'.

What can I do to maintain those variables or manage the session and its variables in a better way so that I can jump between pages without problems like this one?

***Edit 1:***

I've change the code a bit. I've now just put `session_start()` at the beginning of `index_root.php` and `info_user.php` and I have deleted that part in `session.php` and in `form_root.php`. The code becomes:

**form_root.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['sent_user'] == 'user' ) {
        $_SESSION['entidad_info'] = substr( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
        strrpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "=" ) + 1 );
        header("Location: info_usuarios.php");
    }
}
?>
```

Now I don't send the `ss_user` session variable via form and save it again, I just include another variable. However, by doing these changes, now in `form_root.php` I lose the `ss_user`, so I can't reach `info_user.php` because I am redirected to `index.php`. The variables still remain lost when I change between pages.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've been able to save the variables between `form_root.php` and `info_user.php` just by adding `exit;` after the `header()` function in the form file.

The code would stay like this:

```
if ( $_POST['sent_user'] == 'user' ) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['ss_user'] = $_POST['session'];
        $_SESSION['entity_info'] = substr( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
        strrpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "=" ) + 1 );

        header("Location: info_user.php");
        exit;
}
```

This approach solves the specific problem, but I am forced to send the *session* data via form because I cannot access it from `form_root.php`'s `$_SESSION` variable, so I've re-written that part of the code I previously had. However, this is just a partial solution, therefore, I am looking for a complete one yet.